# What is the size of ( variable = &anotherVar )

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference, sizeof

What is the size of ( variable = &anotherVar )

```
int y = 10; // the size of y is 4 bytes
int & x = y; // what is the size of x that receives the address of y
```

Comment: Can't cite the standard on this, but 32 or 64 bits depending on CPU architecture targeted.

Comment: @Corbin : Is it the same size of y ?

Comment: @faressoft probably but it's not defined to be that, so you can't count on it.

Comment: Your question is inconsistent. (variable = & anotherVar) is not the same as type & x + anothervar. Which of the two questions are you asking?

Answer (score 4):

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage (C++11 8.3.2.4)

For the case

```
int y = 10;
int & x = y;
```

the compiler may not use any extra memory; it will just consider `x` to be an alias of `y`. Once `x` is initialized it can't be reassigned to reference another variable, so the compiler can do this.

If a reference is used as a function parameter or in a class/struct, then it will probably be implemented internally as a pointer so the size will be `sizeof(int*)`. Of course, if a function with reference parameters is inlined, then no extra memory will be needed.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about the physical size of the reference type `int&`, it will almost certainly be the same size as the pointer type `int*`, which is typically 4 or 8 bytes on modern architectures (32- or 64-bit processors).

If you want to measure it on your compiler, use this:

```
struct Test { int& x; }
printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(Test));
```

Also note that, technically, your compiler might pad the `Test` struct and give you the wrong answer, but this will probably work fine.

Note that `sizeof(int&)` is the same as `sizeof(int)`, and doesn't tell you exactly how much space an `int&` will use if it is a data member.

Comment: True that `sizeof(int&)` won't tell you much, but `sizeof(int*)` will.

Comment: But `sizeof(Test) == sizeof(int*)` is not guaranteed by the standard (I believe), even discounting padding, although it is true for pretty much any sane architecture/compiler.

Comment: [An overview of this topic](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq22_11.html). I'd wager that pointers factor in the same way as any other type -- that is, if the structs aren't packed then the sizes may be off. Then again, a discussion on struct packing is outside the scope of the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

The result of application of sizeof to a reference or a reference type is the size of the referenced type. (C++ 03, 5.3.3.2)

If your int is 4 bytes (it does not have to be), then so is the reference.

Comment: Technically speaking, your second statement is not true unless the standard also guarantees somewhere that sizeof always and without fail returns the physical size of the type.  By the first statement, a char reference would have sizeof() == 1, but I really doubt a reference to a char is only 8 bits.

Comment: This answer is completely correct, as it talks about the "result of application of sizeof". This is a necessary consequence of the transparency of references. It may or may not answer the actual question (which is a bit ambiguous).

Answer (score 0):

So I think you are confusing pointers and references.

You ask what is (x = &y) ?

But then your example is a reference (X& x = y).

I think you mean what is the size of a pointer?  It is architecture dependent.  To find out what it is  on your paticular target type:

```
cout << sizeof(void*)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple test should clear up any confusion:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f(char &r)
{
  cout << sizeof(r) << endl;
  cout << sizeof(&r) << endl;
}

int main()
{
  char x = 0;
  char &y = x;
  cout << sizeof(y) << endl;
  cout << sizeof(&y) << endl;
  f(x);
  return 0;
}
```

Output (compiled as an x86 32-bit program):

```
1
4
1
4
```